# Force link to switch from in-app browser to real browser

Tags: android, ios, browser, mobile-safari, mobile-chrome

When someone clicks a link to my website on an app like Instagram or TikTok, the link opens in the apps in-app-browser. When they click a link to another site, it also opens in the in-app-browser, even if the link has `target="_blank"`.

Is there a way to force a link to open in the real browser instead of the in-app browser?

Answer (score 1):

There is no guaranteed way to force a link to open in the real browser instead of the in-app browser. This behavior is dependent on the app's settings and can vary across different apps and operating systems.

However, you can try to remove the `target="_blank"` attribute from your link. In some cases, this may cause the link to open in the real browser.